# Optimal integer $k$ for fastest growing function of the form $f(n)=k^{\frac{k(n-1)}{(6+2k)(k+1)}}$

Tags: calculus, functions

If you look closely, the expression

$$k^{\frac{k(n-1)}{(6+2k)(k+1)}}$$

is similar to $k^{n/k}$, in that $k$ is the exponential's base, and the exponent expression is on the order of $1/k$.

I know the optimal integer $k$ for $k^{n/k}$ is $3$ ($e$ is best if you allow non-integers, and I guess $3$ is just the closest integer to $e$). But the constants in the longer expression I give above makes it a little more confusing.

**Motivation:**

I'm thinking about the optimal way to `type` (cost $t$), `copy` (cost $c$), and `paste` (cost $p$) characters in a string, to grow the string the fastest, given a "cost" for each of those 3 actions.

For a strategy of a single `type` followed by periodic `copy`+ $k$ `paste`'s (shorthand: t[cpp...][cpp...]...), the length of the string ($f(n)$) as a function of cost ($n$) grows as

$$k^{\frac{k(n-t)}{(c+kp)(k+1)}}$$

Choosing costs of $t=1$, $c=6$, and $p=2$ (roughly a number of keystrokes for performing each command) yields the expression in the question.

The answer to the question (what integer $k$ maximizes the growth of that function) will be the optimal number of `pastes` to do between each `copy` when using the described strategy.

Comment: so what do you expect from us, to make the 3D graph in k and n?.... Or calculate the gradients?

Comment: Are you implying that those things are necessary for solving this problem? If so, do you have any comments on [Matthew's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2315657/149442), which appears to be at odds with that?

Comment: None yet, because my comment is earlier than the answer 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best $k$ is $6$.

Your function is $\left( k^{k/((6+2k)(k+1))} \right)^{n-1}$, so let $y=k^{k/((6+2k)(k+1))}$.  We want to maximize $y$, which is equivalent to maximizing $\log y$.

Let $g(k)=\log y = \frac{k \log k}{(6+2k)(k+1)}$.

Note that $g(k)<\frac{\log k}{k}$, which is decreasing for $k>e$.

Check that $\frac{\log k}{k}<g(6)$ for $k\ge 45$.

Check that $g(k)\le g(6)$ for $k \le 45$, and the result is proven.